# Proxy or gateway between application and database server

Tags: web-apps, database, proxy

We are going through implementing ISO 27001 processes we have a requirement of having a proxy server between the application and database server, can someone suggest an architecture and tools to use?

We have a straightforward architecture where the web application server takes all the requests and connects to the DB server to fetch, update or insert data. The web server is nginx and the database server is also hosted on Linux and is a MySQL server